# IE11 Developer Tools Blank Network and Profile Tab

Tags: internet-explorer-11, ie-developer-tools

Extensively used IE9 Developer Tools and I just updated to IE11 "11.0.2" and the Developer Tools are garbage.

My Network and Profile Tabs are blank.
Is there a "special" setting that I'm missing in order to enable them, or could there be a specific windows hot fix between the IE11 RTM and 11.0.2 that I may be missing?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem (version 11.0.9600.17633) on WIN7

Only on one of 4 accounts. Reinstalling IE11, etc did not help.

With regedit, I renamed HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer 
to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer Old

I logged off, then logged on again and started Internet Explorer. This recreated the key. The network tab and profiler tab are no longer blank. Internet Explorer settings have been lost however. I assume the settings and state of Internet Explorer are the same as just after creating a new account.

Comment: I did this, but only deleted the IEDev tools folder, logged off and back on, IE network Tab works a treat now.

Comment: Where's the "IEDev tools folder" located?

Comment: In case this helps anyone else, he means the "IEDevTools" node under :  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer. Strangely some machines don't have it and after renaming and restarting, it didn't get recreated and the same problem exists for me.

Answer (score 4):

The network tab was not working for me on Windows 10 Creators Update (Version 1703 OS Build 150063.540) in IE OR Edge.

After trying the various registry changes mentioned by others without success, I  removed Internet Explorer as a Window Feature (Control Panel > Programs and Features > Turn Windows Features on or off).

I rebooted and opened Edge and the network tab was working again.

Then I went back into Programs and Feature and added IE back as in installed feature.  I rebooted and now the network tab is working in both IE and Edge.

Comment: Disabling the feature, rebooting, then re-enabling and rebooting again worked for me - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To make blank Network Panel/Profiler Panel appear again(also pin F12 developer tool not working either), delete the following registry DWORD key:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet
>   Explorer\Main\TabProcGrowth

This key could be recreated automatically.

I still have this problem using IE 11.0.9600.18097 on Win 7 [Version 6.1.7601]. I post my solution here in case someone faces the same situation like me, that your company doesn't allow updating IE on your own. My

Possible related issue tracker:
https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/808417/ie-11-win-7-developer-tools-does-not-pin

Comment: Helped me on Win10

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution: install the following patch from Microsoft and restart your computer:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=46507

Comment: I didn't have the TabProcGrowth key. Installing this security patch worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

This helped me for IE 11, Windows 10:

```
sc config diagnosticshub.standardcollector.service start=demand
```

(see https://www.systemcamp.com/network-collection-agent-failed-to-start-in-ie-11-or-edge/)

Comment: Now I run it from services manually anytime I need network tab in IE.

Comment: This worked for the Legacy Edge browser as well :)

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely worth getting the latest updates.

There shouldn't be any special settings. The only special/different thing about the network and profiler tools are the two tools that weren't rebuilt in IE11 and were just themed. However they should most definitely work just fine. Though there are some timing bugs that can cause the tools to hang and crash :(. But, that doesn't seem to be happening for you.

I'm a bit of a loss as to make recommendations on how to fix the issue as we've not seen the issue before (I work on the F12 tools at Microsoft).

If you try a different user account does the same issue happen? Is it happening on all your machines or just one? Does it happen on all pages or just some? (try both an intranet and internet site.)

Comment: I am also having the issue. IE11 (Version 11.0.9600.17207 and Update versions: 11.0.10)

Comment: I'm having this issue as well, Windows 8.1 N, 64bit, all updates installed.

Comment: me too- win 8, 6.3 build 9600. ie11.0.9600.17239. Update versions: 11.0.11. Prod Id: 00150-200000-00003-aa459.

Comment: I'm encountering the same issue. 
Internet Explorer 11. Version: 11.0.9600.18231. Update Versions: 11.0.29 (KB3139929). Product ID: 00150-20000-00003-AA459.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new local account, logged into that account and that solved this problem for me.  All of the tabs in the developer tools work and I can now dock the developer tools as well which I could never do before.

more info:

Not sure if this is the full answer but this appears to be related to settings on your computer more then IE itself.  For whatever reason I could not change visual settings or apply themes or change the desktop wallpaper.  I followed all the online setting changes for fixing those things.  Basically it can be setting changes in group policies/registry settings that disable this.  However I'm pretty sure at one point I had a virus on my computer and that destroyed my settings so there was no real undoing of all the damage that it had done.  So creating a new account was my only answer.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this would fix the issue but just to make sure it is not being caused by an extension have you tried running IE without extensions?

from run: iexplore.exe -extoff

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me and the answer was that my machine (win8.1) wasn't being patched per the group policy since the rest of the company's on win7 and the patches are controlled.

When I forced the update-- there's a link on the windows update dialog box that says "Check online for updates from Microsoft Update". I got a gig a of stuff to dl and installed it and we were fine after that.

NOTHING until then- wiping bits of the registry, uninstall ie11, reinstall, etc, worked.

Answer (score 0):

Change the value data in DWORD "TabProcGrowth" that located in "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main" to 1. close and open IE11 .

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 0):

For me, Network tab stopped working one day and following worked:

Restart **Microsoft (R) Diagnostics Hub Standard Collector** Service

Answer (score 0):

Just close IE11 and all its tabs and reopen